# CSS overflow, border-radius, mix-blend-mode, will-change : Depending on the width of the screen, the position of the element changes

Tags: overflow, mix-blend-mode, border-radius, will-change

I need mix-blend-mode element in my project, so I use `mix-blend-mode` property.

It looked fine at first, but as the screen narrowed, it changed to an unexpected appearance.

Also `overflow: hidden` doesn't work, so blue comes out of the corner.

I run this code in Chrome browser.

[Looks different depending on screen width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbaJW.png)

```
.card{
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50vh;
    background-color: pink;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 24px;
}
.blend{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    mix-blend-mode: color-dodge;
    will-change: transform;
}
```

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="blend"></div>
</div>
```

Here's my code.
Please let me know why this problem happen.
Thank you!

I think `border-radius`, `overflow`, `mix-blend-mode` and `will-change` properties seems to be contributing to this problem, but still I don't know ★why★ this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not super clear what you are hoping for, but if you're expecting the inner div to match the dimensions of the outer div then remove `will-change: transform`. With the 100% width and height it should already adhere to the parent div.

For reference: https://jsfiddle.net/santmzyq/4/

Hope this helps.